# Changed a url in theme header in wordpress, my header is gone

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, wordpress-theming

I have no knowledge of Wordpress (so please accept my excuse for asking weird question). I have a website built with wordpress and used Avada theme. Due to website movement, we updated all urls to the new one and everything was perfect; except one url which was in background of the theme;

**We found the url and changed it directly in Database using phpmyadmin (data was serialized)**

then the header was screwed up. The question is how can I bring it back as previous; I modified the data in DB and set the values as it was but still it's not showing my header.

Any idea, how can I return it back? Appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have backup of serialize array use base64_encode function. You can do it also online http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_encode/.

Encode it then go to wp-admin->appearance->theme options-> backup past encoded string there and click import. Will work I just checked :)

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

After serializing array php is keeping also string length , so problem is that you changed string but forgot to change string size.

For example at first you have string like this `

a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:3:"url";}

Then you changed it to

a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:3:"new_url";}

But you also should change s:3, because now php can't unserialize this string after changing it to this it will work

a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:7:"new_url";}

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's correct; but I had a copy of the previous serialized data so I just copied and pasted that one back, but still does not work. I know the serialization in PHP but I think it's different in Wordpress and the issue comes from wordpress

Comment: Also if your theme options (serialized string in db) become bigger then 256 symbols after inserting mysql cut it. It something like cheat` It can came very huge by updating but you can't insert big string, also if it is not confidential could you provide string I will check is it valid?Or you already have checked?If it is valid so it is problem that I have described.

Comment: Yes it is valid, I did checked it. I am trying your second answer; hopefully that works. what do you mean by *cut it*?

Comment: OK; before that could tell me what do you mean by *cut it* because the amount of symbols in my serialized string is 297

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52410/discussion-between-davit-and-javad)